# Make mouse behavior in gvim same as in console vim

Tags: vim, configuration, mouse

I always worked with vim in console (ssh, remote etc..), and always used my mouse as xterm mouse, not vim.

My typical task for mouse is:

1. Select some console text (without moving vim cursor or somethink like this)
2. Paste text to console by middle-click (in insert mode this text will be entered, in normal mode like a command. For example middle-click pasting 'iii' switch to insert and put 'ii' text)
3. Right click for my xterm-menu. I use it only for paste from X11 buffer.

Last time I trying to use gvim. Better resolution, better colors, etc.
But I have problem with mouse.

I was tried switch off mouse (set mouse=c), tried switch off expand selection (set mousemodel=popup) but all this not the same as my 3 list points above.

How to switch my mouse to console/xterm mode? (:be xterm not the same, its still move cursor in selection).

Any plugins? Configs?

Comment: The behavior you want exists only because Vim is run *in* your terminal emulator. Because there's nothing between you and GVim, and specifically no terminal emulation layer, I doubt any setting in GVim would allow you to reach your goal.

Comment: WTF is “better resolution” in gvim?

Comment: If 2 and 3 were ever the default Xterm behavior, it is not anymore. Anyway, Ctrl+Shift+Mouse selects text to primary (what you call X11 buffer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse behavior you describe here is your terminal emulator feature, not vim one. You may make terminal vim handle mouse much like GUI one assuming your terminal emulator supports passing mouse events down to application (most do) (likely requires having appropriate terminfo entry on the remote machine; I actually did not bother investigating since I do not use mouse with vim), but not the opposite.

I.e. your question is incorrect: *if terminal vim was configured to take control over the mouse* its mouse behavior is the same as in gvim (except for some elements like menus, icons and scrollbar not present in terminal version), but if it was not you cannot be right when talking about “mouse behavior in vim” because it is “mouse behavior in xterm”.

---

About colors and gvim: I [have a branch](https://bitbucket.org/ZyX_I/vim/commits/24-bit-xterm) that enables true (24 bit) color in terminal (i.e. makes vim use guifg/guibg properties in place of ctermfg/ctermbg). Obviously, requires support from terminal. Currently only konsole (KDE terminal emulator) and dev version of st (since commit http://git.suckless.org/st/commit/?id=8dde8cde41caa311718d2b990ea3356272ee25ee) support true color. Xterm “supports” it by using nearest color from 8-bit palette.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, now I understand that question was incorrect. I should ask: how to set my gvim mouse like my lxterminal mouse. But its still actual ;) I suppose its impossible,

Comment: @KorjavinIvan This should be possible if you patch Vim source code. AFAIR it would not be a trivial patch though. With plugin you may not achieve exactly the same behavior.